# Font-awesome is showing some weird icons

Tags: android, encoding, font-awesome, android-typeface

I am using font awesome in Android app. It is not showing that real icons. Instead I get some strange text. For example I was expecting to see the `arrow-left` and what I got is this(shown in image).

[image]

```
android:text="@string/fa_arrow_left"

userTV.setTypeface(TypeFaces.get(this.getApplicationContext(), "fa"));
```

And here is the TypeFaces Class.

```
public class TypeFaces {
    private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(Context c, String name) {
        synchronized (cache) {
            if (!cache.containsKey(name)) {
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                        c.getAssets(),
                        String.format("fonts/%s.ttf", name)
                );
                cache.put(name, t);
            }
            return cache.get(name);
        }
    }
}
```

In strings.xml `<string name="fa_arrow_left">&#xf060;</string>`

The fa.ttf is placed in `main > assets > fonts`

Downloaded the font from https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf

Anyway be **☺**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! Solved it. Actually the code for that character was not available in the version I was using. Downloaded the latest font from fontawesome website and it worked. Solving the problem took a whole day. Thanks to all those who tried in background to help me.